# Why does my bot.get_user(user_id) return me none in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm coding a discord bot with python and I have a problem.
Here is my code :

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands

#Créer une instance du bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

#Donner le jeton pour l'identifier
jeton = "Here is the token"

#Detecter quand le bot est allumé
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Prêt")
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game('Hello World !'))
    print("Bonjour")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    user_id = payload.user_id
    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    canal = payload.channel_id
    message = payload.message_id
    membre = bot.get_user(user_id)

    if canal == 826772563715555358 and message == 826773226675896340 and emoji == "python":
        print("Grade ajouté !")
        print(membre)


@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(payload):

    emoji = payload.emoji.name
    canal = payload.channel_id
    message = payload.message_id

    if canal == 826772563715555358 and message == 826773226675896340 and emoji == "python":
        print("Grade enlevé !")



#Créer la commande !regles
@bot.command()
async def regles(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Les règles : \n1. Pas d'insulte \n2. Pas de double compte \n3. Pas de spam")

#Créer la commande !bienvenue
@bot.command()
async def bienvenue(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    pseudo = member.mention
    await ctx.send(f"Bienvenue {pseudo} ! ")

#tester l'erreur de la commande
@bienvenue.error
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Veuillez préciser une personne")


#Connecter le bot
bot.run(jeton)
```

But in the on_raw_reaction_add, when I print the member, it returns me none. Why ? To get it, I used bot.get_user(user_id).
Thank you very much.

PS : Sorry for the variables and comments in french because I am french

Comment: I don't find the answer on the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Usually and the most common reason for events to return `none` instead of a valid member is caused by unabled member intents.

Events that require access to a member must require the member intents to be enabled.
Intents can be enabled from Discord developer portal, from there you only need to make sure you have enabled Member in intents within the "Bot" category. You'd then need to define and use the intents in your bot code in the section you define your bot or client:

Use the following code in your code to define and access Discord's member intents

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Make sure to replace `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')` with the code above

Comment: So where have I to write this in my code ?

Comment: at the start, replace bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!') with the intents plus the bot

Comment: How did this go?

Comment: ```RuntimeError: Event loop is closed```